# authlogic - do I still need Rails sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authlogic

I'm a newbie to Rails and am starting a new project that uses AuthLogic. I'm just a little confused about whether AuthLogic provides everything I need to store session state, or whether I still have to include the Rails mechanism (rake db:sessions:create).

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need sessions but you don't necessarily need `db:sessions:create` for that as it's only needed for the db session store. You can use the default cookie store and all the data will be stored encrypted in the cookie.